# Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not matched when server responds 304

Tags: web, xmlhttprequest, cors

I have an API server `api.example.com` and two websites `a.example.com`, `b.example.com`. To enable CORS, I set up CORS headers for them.

An XHR request from `a.example.com` will get the response headers from `api.example.com`

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: https://a.example.com
access-control-max-age: 0
vary: origin
```

Similarly, an XHR request from `b.example.com` will get the response headers from `api.example.com`

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: https://b.example.com
access-control-max-age: 0
vary: origin
```

When I fetches resource `GET api.example.com/articles/1` in `a.example.com` and then go to `b.example.com` do the same action to fetch the resource. The browser will use `if-none-match` headers to get the resource and receives a `304` response code from server. Then it complains that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header has a value `https://a.example.com` that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin `https://b.example.com` is therefore not allowed access.

I think browser uses its cache when `304` is responded and find out `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is cached as `a.example.com`'s resource therefore refuse to fulfill the request.

How can I mitigate the issue here? Any thought?

Answer (score 3):

Requests are cached, including its content and headers.

When you access a the first time. The response is generated and saved in the cache.

When you access b afterwards. The 304 response comes with no header and no content, all it does is instruct the browser to use the cache. The cached response has headers for the other site and it throws an access error.

These two requests should not be answered with a 304 since they are not equivalent.

`If-None-Match` means that pages are identified with en `ETag`. An arbitrary string generated by the application to identify a cachable version of a page.

You should modify the application to generate different `ETag` for different `Origin`.